# Data Structures and Algorithms Asypmtotic Notation

Tags: data-structures

I'm currently in the progress of getting familiar with asymptotic notations for Big Theta, and I was wondering if I could have someone double check my practice.

Problem: f(n)=2(3n^3+2n+1)^3, find big theta notation, assume conditions have been met for big O and omega.

My solution: 2 * (3n^(3+3) + 2n^3 + 1^3), I add the exponent 3 to the power inside
6n^6 + 2n^3 + 2, I multiply the constant 2 to the values in parenthesis
n^6, f(n)= theta(n^6), I take the highest power and drop the constants

Can anyone please let me know if I did this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with asymptotic notation; it is high-school algebra. No, this is not how you raise something to the power 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quiet simple.

1. We say that `f(n)` is `O(g(n))` if exists a constant C that the limit of `C * g(n) / f(n)` is constant.
2. We say that `f(n)` is `Big Omega(g(n))` (sorry, no LaTeX here) if if exists a constant C that the limit of `C * f(n) / g(n)` is a constant (*kind of* "the opposite" of the big O notation)

We say that a function is `theta(g(n))` if **both** (1) and (2) co-exist.

Now, we need to find a function that behaves almost as `f(n)`, that will suppress it from above with a constant C, and will be suppressed by it with another constant D.

It is easy to prove that when talking about `f(n)` that is a ***polynomial function***, it is always `theta(n^k)` where *k* is the *degree* ("the highest power") of that polynomial.

***However, you need to know how to prove it!***

Anyhow, you were wrong when expanding `f(n)`. The real expansion is:

```
f(n) = 54 n^9 + 108 n^7 + 54 n^6 + 72 n^5 + 72 n^4 + 34 n^3 + 24 n^2 + 12 n + 2
```

with `C = 55` and `D = 53` you get `53 * n^9 <= f(n) <= 55 * n^9` when `n` is large enough, (or, the two limits (1) and (2) are constants)

Comment: Hi Kerek, thanks for your response. While i did find the information about proving this useful, I don't believe it is required for this exercise. I wanted to see if I had the correct methodology for finding the theta(n^k). What is the value of K in this example? Thanks.

Comment: @Lifeofnaye You miscalculated the `^3`. It **isn't** multiplication, it is **power of 3**, which is completely different!

Comment: @Lifeofnaye but anyhow, if you know how to prove what I have explained, it is sufficient to say that the degree of `2 * (3n^(3+3) + 2n^3 + 1^3)` is ***9*** (not 6!), and that this is the "leading" part of the polynomial when `n` is large enough. (But this is only after you really got into the O notations)

Comment: Thanks I went back to double check my work and awarded you the green check for an explanation of the concept!